# tcp socket, cannot bind to port - in use

Tags: c++, tcp, port

Ive got a c++ program that acts as a server (sends/receives). I'm trying to connect to the port that the server is using (say 2222). However, the message I'm getting is that the port is already bound to. The port is in use. I'm wondering how can I connect to this open port (bearing in mind the c++ tcp program is closed source)? I can change the source of the c++ program if needed, but it seems strange that I cannot just connect to the port it's using. I wonder do I need to implement threading in the tcp program, so that the send and receive's are using a different port?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ports involved in a TCP connection. The incoming port that the server is listening on and the outgoing port that the client is connecting on.

They don't need to be the same port.

If both client and server are running on the same machine, then they can't be the same port because that port is already in use (by the server, presumably).

If that's the case, bind the client socket to port 0 instead, which basically says "give me any available port".